# OpenAPI generated code by openapi-generator-cli

Tags: javascript, yaml, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

So I've generated some code with the petstore.yaml from the official OpenAPI website using openapi-generator-cli. But when I test it with postman it show error code 400 and the error message body as below:

```
{
    "message": "request should have required property 'headers'",
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": ".headers",
            "message": "should have required property 'headers'",
            "errorCode": "required.openapi.validation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please, help me! I'm stuck!

I have tried writing my .yaml file, but it's still the same. But one thing to remember is I haven't tried to change any code in the generated files. I'm still new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which server (what language/framework) did you generate? Which exactly endpoint are your calling from Postman? How are you calling that endpoint, what data (request body, headers, etc.) are you using?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you.  This means posting, at a minimum, some of your `openapi` schema (specifically the endpoint and objects) and your CLI arguments.  Posting an error message with no context doesn't help anyone.  Feel free to browse some of the [other `openapi-generator` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openapi-generator) to get an idea of what is expected in a similar question.  Once you've updated your post, I'm confident you will get the help you seek.

Comment: Thank so much for the effort, everyone. I really appreciate it. It's been stressful I've not got the time to reply. It turns out it had something to do with the npm version.

Comment: But if you still want to reproduce the error, I will add how to to it later because it's n8ght time for me now.

Comment: If you were able to discover the solution on your own, it always helps to provide your solution as an answer to your own question.  This can help others in the future in the event they encounter the same issue.  However, even if you do provide an answer, please update the question with more information to assist others in determining if the provided solution is relevant to their situation as well.